# Creating if/than statement to move files to another location based on value of 1 column?

Tags: shell, files

I have thousands of xyz (latitude,longitude,elevation) text files that I want to separate by latitude or longitude. How and what commands could I use to create an "if latitude(column1) is greater than -1.00, than move to this directory"? for all files in my original directory.

I have been close with a couple different commands using grep or awk but not working exactly how I would like.

example list of files

```
2004_2006-361383_Morecambe_Bay_Heysham_Channel_s.xyz
2004_2006-361385_River_Mersey_Langton_Dock_Entrance_s.xyz
2004_2006-361399_Thames_Estuary_Gore_Channel_s.xyz
```

here is a sample of the first 10 lines of a file, many of these files have millions and millions of lines

```
-002.9584650 54.0087979 -5.3
-002.9416586 54.0326371 -1.3
-002.9307806 54.0323594 -8.5
-002.9644657 53.9985145 0.8
-002.9680185 54.0019534 -10
-002.9524820 54.0183868 -5
-002.9439942 54.0179227 -4.2
-002.9569578 54.0183595 -5.4
-002.9372192 54.0224494 -3.2
-002.9535454 54.0178188 -4.3
```

Comment: can you edit your post with file names, or file content ?

Comment: you say if any column is greater than -1, move the (file?) - will a whole file be moved, or will different lines in a single file qualify for more than one "move" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't specify. I would like if any value in column 1 is above or below the number I want, than move.

Answer (score 0):

If file have no funny name (that is space)

global sort

```
awk 'FNR==1 { printf "mv %s ../dir%d\n",FILENAME,$1 ; next ; }' * | bash
```

north/south sort

```
awk 'FNR==1 { printf "mv %s ../%s\n",FILENAME,$1<0?"south":"north" ; next ; }' * | bash
```

where

- `FNR == 1` operate on first line of file
- `printf` and `%d`  will resolve to int part of column 1
- replace `| bash` by `| head -10` to check it is OK
- `next` will skip remaining line an go to next file.
- `$1<0?"south":"north"` will select either south or north

I supposed you want to move the whole file, and that all latitude are either above or below 0.

Comment: when I used this, it dissolves my files and just creates new files merging them together. Essentially, I would like to keep original file intact, just move them to a new directory based on if/than search criteria that I choose.